# How to check if lines in a file are formatted correctly

Tags: linux

What command would I use on linux to see if the lines in a file are correctly formatted? So if a text file (names.txt) had the lines;
`{"first":joe "last":smith}` and `"{"first:joe last":smith]` it would show me that the first line is correct and the 2nd line is not.

Comment: What format do you use? It seems similar to JSON, but string values must be quoted in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple grep like this:

```
grep -v -E '^{".*?":.*? ".*?":.*?}$' names.txt
```

Assuming, that your example provided is no real JSON (missing the comma after the first value).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why I didn't think to grep it. I was overthinking this. Thank you.